# crystal report web service operations

Tags: web-services, crystal-reports

How can I use the Crystal Report web service operations listed by the web service?

I created a visual studio web project and created a webservice for the crystal reports. `http://localhost:52567/CrystalReportsWebSite1/CrystalReport1Service.asmx` it displays a list of "supported operations"

```
CrystalReport1Service

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

DoParameterPrompting
DrillGraph
DrillPartGraph
Export
FindGroup
FindText
GetAvailableExportFormats
GetGroupLevelData
GetInitialReportParts
GetLastPageNumber
GetPage
GetParamPromptingInfo
GetPromptParameterFields
GetReportEngineType
GetReportInfo
GetReportParts
GetTotaller
NavigateToReportPart
Refresh
ResolveParamPromptingResult
TestReport
```

I followed the numerous examples online and they have worked flawlessly to serve and consume a crystal report using a web service.  But none have shown how to use these methods and I cannot figure it out.
My main objective is to get the parameter names for the report, and it seems these operations could accomplish that.

I'm still learning about services and such, so I may be way off in my understanding of what these operations are for.